# command line option

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
    {
    cout << argv[1] << endl;
    if (argv[1]=="-r") cout << "success\n";
    }
```

"success" does not print out. When I run: $ ./hearts -r
the only thing that comes out is:

-r

which makes me sooo confused

Comment: You can't compare strings with `==`, welcome to the world of `C`/`C++` ;D Welcome to SO as well, nice profile pic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1],"-r")==0) cout << "success\n";
```

to compare the argument with string literal.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go ahead and tell you that you don't want `strcmp`. The C++ way to handle command-line arguments is to turn them into `std::string`s as soon as possible:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  // Make a vector of all command-line arguments
  std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc);
  // Now we can use std::string's operator==
  if (args.size() > 1 && args[1] == "-r") {
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You can compare two `std::string`s with the `==` operator. In the case of `args[1] == "-r"`, the `const char[]` string literal is converted to a `std::string` for comparison. In your code, `argv[1]=="-r"` compares two independent pointers which will not be equal - it does not compare the contents of the C-style strings.

Comment: Then I'm going to tell you that you don't want `std::endl`. Just use `'\n'` instead (it's even shorter!). And for option parsing you probably want something like `getopt`, not manual `if`/`else` checks.

Comment: @melpomene But `\n` doesn't flush the stream.

Comment: It does if `cout` is a terminal. Also, it doesn't matter here because the program is about to exit anyway, which flushes all streams.

Comment: @melpomene I think `std::endl` is more appropriate for the sake of teaching. I wouldn't want to give people bad habits.

Comment: IMHO `endl` is a bad habit.

Comment: +1 Because - arguments about `endl` aside - this actually shows C++ code.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using `==` on two pointers. It will check whether the pointers are equal, not whether the point at the same data.

To compare two C strings, use `strcmp` like this:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-r") == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `strcmp` to compare the two strings. For `==` to be true, your two strings would have to refer to the same memory location, which can't happen, as `"-r"` is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strcmp()` and it will work as expected. When you use `==` you compare pointers, and they cannot be the same.

Answer (score 1):

In C, string are character-arrays (pointers to a sequence of characters). In your code, equality operator just compares two pointer values, which are absolutely different. You should use `strcmp` function, or use `string` class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring> // <-- here

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    cout << argv[1] << endl;
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-r") == 0) // <-- and here
        cout << "success\n";
}
```

OR

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> // <-- here

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    cout << argv[1] << endl;
    if (string(argv[1]) == "-r") // <-- and here
        cout << "success\n";
}
```